# Trying to make a simple Jinja2 extension to handle NDB futures

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-datastore

Okay, a little background: I'm using [NDB](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/), and perhaps more relevantly, its implementation of "futures". Basically, they represent asynchronously running work, and can have their result fetched by calling `get_result()` on them.

Currently, when creating the context to provide the template, I have to de-future all the futures before passing them to Jinja2, this is less efficient, causes duplicate code and perhaps most importantly: is messy.

I want an extension that does this for me.

I want this:

```
Logged in as {{ user.name }}
```

To effectively be:

```
Logged in as {{ user.get_result().name }}
```

Only when `user` is an instance of the `Future` class.

Comment: I don't think this will buy you much - template rendering takes a small amount of time compared to the time spent doing RPCs, and you have to wait on all the futures before you can finish template rendering anyway.

Comment: When you have things like HTML-escaping, filters, i18n, it starts to slow things down a bit, not a lot, but a small improvement is still an improvement. Even if it's only a handful of MS.

Comment: You're still going to take that time, though - all this gains you is a fraction of that during which RPCs can keep executing. Evaluating the template is the first thing the template engine does, so you don't gain much at all.